# Requesting a file through Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, setinterval

I have tried this as an answer from my previous question, but it does not work it just reports 500 Internal Server Error and Firebug does not report any details of the error:

```
(function worker() {
$.ajax({
   url: 'buildmarkers.inc.php',
   type: 'POST', 
   success: function(data) {
$('.result').html(data);
},
complete: function() {
   // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
setTimeout(worker, 30000);
}
});
})();
```

when I try it like this it is working:

```
<?php include('buildmarkers.inc.php')?>
```

Comment: The error logs will offer a huge clue.

Comment: Can you add your php code too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your real question is, "Why am I getting a 500 error." and the answer to that can't be determined without the code for buildmarkers.inc.php. You aren't seeing anything in firebug because it's a server side error. If you modify your javascript and add an error function, you'll see it fail on the client.

```
(function worker() {
$.ajax({
   url: 'buildmarkers.inc.php',
   type: 'POST', 
   success: function(data) {
     $('.result').html(data);
   },
   error: function(data){
     console.log("Save me Tom Cruise! The server is on fire!");
   },
   complete: function() {
     // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
     setTimeout(worker, 30000);
   }
  });
})();
```

Comment: Well my real question is why it is working one way and not the other way, what is different in ajax request compared to javascript include?
And I did try POST and GET methods on ajax.

Comment: When you require the file, PHP is processing it within the context of the requiring script. Maybe you are meaning to do the ajax call to the requiring script instead of the buildmarkers.inc.php? If you hit http://example.com/buildmarkers.inc.php that is the same result you'd get with ajax. What you need to do is look at the PHP error log to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax call will get the file with relative path of URI (based on DOCUMENT_ROOT or webserver), it might be different with include() in PHP that uses absolute path of current script file. You might:

1. Check the folder structure of your project, is there any difference between your script path and "buildmarkers.inc.php"'s one?
2. Does it have any rewrite rule on you webserver?
3. You should check the error log of your webserver, it should show helpful messages.

Comment: I tried looking into the PHP log, but can not find anything, can not find log at all. And php.ini, says [error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log], but there is no file there.

Comment: It should be in webserver error log file. You should check the VirtualHost configuration for your localhost, then see the error log in that file (Nginx: error_log, Apache: ErrorLog)